# Add text to ggplot (add number of differentially expressed genes to MA plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a MA plot function, add the number of significantly expressed genes to the plot.
MA plots show differentially expressed genes between two groups with their fold-change and the average expression.
I am trying to add the total number of differentially expressed genes to the upper right side of the plot. Instead of "hard coding" the x and y coordinates, a reallative localisation would be prefered.

Maybe the numbers should be added to the df cotaing the data to be plotted instead of a new one? Any advise would me much appreciated!

## Example data

```
set.seed(47)
gene_creator <- paste("gene",1:100,sep="")
genes = sample(gene_creator,8)

dex_A <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_A",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=8),
  adj.P.Val = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=8),
  AveExpr = sample(c(30:36), replace=T, size=8)
)

dex_B <- data.frame(
  gene = genes,
  group = "group_B",
  logFC = sample(c(-5:5), replace=T, size=8),
  adj.P.Val = sample(c(0.01,1), replace=T, size=8),
  AveExpr = sample(c(30:36), replace=T, size=8)
)

dex_df <- rbind(dex_A, dex_B)
```

## Solution (not working)

```
library('tidyverse')
library('ggrepel')

## find min max genes
minmax <- bind_rows(dex_df %>%
                          filter(adj.P.Val < 0.05) %>%
                          group_by(group) %>%
                          slice_max(logFC, n = 3) %>%
                          mutate(rank = "top5"),
                        dex_df %>%
                          filter(adj.P.Val < 0.05) %>%
                          group_by(group) %>%
                          slice_min(logFC, n = 3) %>%
                          mutate(rank = "min5"))

## get numbers
numbers <- dex_df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(
    n_up = sum(adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & logFC > 0.5),
    n_down = -sum(adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & logFC < 0.5)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(-group, names_to = "direction", values_to = "n")

# colors significance
colors_sig <- c("#999999", "#0072B2", "#D55E00")
names(colors_sig) <- c("NA", "Up", "Down")



# make MA plot
make_plot_MA <- function(dex_df, minmax, numbers, comp){
  # get Min Max for comp
  MINmax <- minmax %>% filter(group == comp)
  # numbers of difEx
  numb4text <- numbers %>% filter(group == comp)
  # plot
  dex_df %>%
    mutate(lab = ifelse(dex_df$gene %in% minmax$gene, as.character(dex_df$gene), NA)) %>%
    mutate(col =  ifelse(dex_df$adj.P.Val > 0.05, "NS", ifelse(logFC > 0, 'Up', 'Down'))) %>%
    filter(group == comp) %>%
    #filter(adj.P.Val < 0.05) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = AveExpr, y = logFC, label = lab, color = col)) +
    geom_point()+ 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    xlab ("Log2 mean expression") +
    ylab ("Log2 fold change") +
    geom_label_repel(color = 'black', min.segment.length = 0) +
    geom_point(data = . %>% filter(gene %in% minmax$gene), color = "black") +
    ggtitle(comp) +
    scale_color_manual(values = colors_sig) +
    geom_text(data=numb4text, aes(x=34, y=6, label=n))
  
}

make_plot_MA(dex_df, MinMax, numbers, 'group_A')
```

Comment: maybe you hould add the packages you are using? I am not sure where the `geom_label_repel` function comes from

Comment: @juan_bzt I agree in general that questions should include non-base packages. In this case, I believe it's from `ggrepel`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added the two packages used to the 'solution' part

Comment: the last line of the "make_plot_MA" function should be `geom_text(data=numb4text, aes(x=max(dex_df$AveExpr), y=max(dex_df$logFC), label=n))`

In that way your text will always be on the top right

Comment: I get an error: Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 5th layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `colour = col`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: This error is strange because I do not define the color in the geom_text?

Comment: @SebastianHesse you could add the color to geom point
` ggplot(a, aes(x = AveExpr, y = logFC, label = lab)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=col))`

Comment: @juan_bzt the error seems to be related to the geom_text, not the geom_point. Maybe I need to give ggplot all eas individualy instead of all together?

Comment: @SebastianHesse I think thats because you inherit aestetics, try
`geom_text(inherit.aes = F, data=numb4text, aes(x=max(dex_df$AveExpr), y=max(dex_df$logFC), label=n))`

in the last line of the function

Comment: @juan_bzt That did the trick! Now its plotting the numbers. The new problem is, that the two numbers are plotted over each other instead of over/under each other. Once this is solved I will complete the solution to the question here. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: i worked out a solution that splits the numbers part. does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
make_plot_MA <- function(dex_df, minmax, numbers, comp){
  # get Min Max for comp
  MINmax <- minmax %>% filter(group == comp)
  # numbers of difEx
  numb4text <- numbers %>% filter(group == comp)
  label.up=paste("up:", numb4text$n[1])
  label.down=paste("down:", numb4text$n[2])
  # plot
  dex_df %>%
    mutate(lab = ifelse(dex_df$gene %in% minmax$gene, as.character(dex_df$gene), NA)) %>%
    mutate(col =  ifelse(dex_df$adj.P.Val > 0.05, "NS", ifelse(logFC > 0, 'Up', 'Down'))) %>%
    filter(group == comp) %>%
    #filter(adj.P.Val < 0.05) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = AveExpr, y = logFC, label = lab, color = col)) +
    geom_point()+ 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    xlab ("Log2 mean expression") +
    ylab ("Log2 fold change") +
    geom_label_repel(color = 'black', min.segment.length = 0) +
    geom_point(data = . %>% filter(gene %in% minmax$gene), color = "black") +
    ggtitle(comp) +
    scale_color_manual(values = colors_sig) +
    geom_text(inherit.aes = F,aes(x=max(dex_df$AveExpr), y=max(dex_df$logFC), label=label.up))+
    geom_text(inherit.aes = F,aes(x=max(dex_df$AveExpr), y=max(dex_df$logFC)-1, label=label.down))
  
  
}

make_plot_MA(dex_df, minmax, numbers, 'group_A')
```

[image: plot with labels]